# Is it sinful for a brahmin to live in Magadh Mahajanpad?

Tags: history

Although Magadh Mahajanpad is part of Aryavrata but I have heard that it is sinful for brahmins to live in Magadh Mahajanpad.

Is is always sinful or was it sinful only for a limited time period ?

Is it sinful only for brahmins or for everyone ?

Because Magadh Mahajanpad is very crucial for revival of hinduism in India. PusyaMitra, Guptas both were main revivalist of hinduism and both ruled from Magadh.

How true is it ?